# Joining four tables to get data from left table

Tags: sql

I have
`Table1 (profileName,asset status,asset_Name,BaseName)`
`Table 2(TITLE,Role etc)` Title is linked to table1 with profile name
`Table 3(Base_Name,Role_Id)` Base is linked to table1 with BaseName
`Table 4(Role ID,Rolename)` Role ID is linked to table3 with Role_Id)

Now I want to get data base on Role from the table 1.
for example

```
Table 1
Test-POD    AVAILABLE FOR SERVICE   XYLENE          Test-Base
Test-N      AVAILABLE FOR SERVICE   X1              Test-Base
Test-N      AVAILABLE FOR SERVICE   X1              Test-Base
Test-N      AVAILABLE FOR SERVICE   X1              Test-Base
Test-POD    UNAVAILABLE FOR SERVICE XYLENE          Test-Base
Test-POD    UNAVAILABLE FOR SERVICE XYLENE          Test-Base
Test-POD    UNAVAILABLE FOR SERVICE XYLENE          Test-Base
```

Table2(has data of Test-POD)

```
Test-POD    Role1   
Test-POD    Role2
```

Table3(has role id for Test-N)

```
Test-Base    95D90BD1-6A31-4CB7-895A-1CDF3FBA428D(Uid)
Test-Base    95D90BD1-6A31-4CB7-895A-1CDF3FBA428D
Test-Base    95D90BD1-6A31-4CB7-895A-1CDF3FBA428D
```

Table4

```
Test-Role           95D90BD1-6A31-4CB7-895A-1CDF3FBA428D
Test-Role-POD1      DCFA3F6B-066E-4C1E-858C-652520B9BABD
Test-Role-POD       EF3E9A85-E709-4CD4-8F04-8570B3CBC2CC
```

Want to filter based on role selected.Tried below query

```
    SELECT 
      distinct(COUNT(Exception.asset_status)) AS CountOfasset_status1, 
      Exception.asset_name, Exception.asset_description
    FROM 
      (((dbo.SATV_REP_EXCEPTION Exception 
      Left outer Join dbo.SATV_PROCEDURE_ROLE Proc_Role ON 
       (Exception.profile_name = Proc_Role.TITLE and 
       Proc_Role.ROLE_NAME='Test-Role-POD1'))
     Left Outer Join dbo.SATV_COR_SCHEDULE_OCCURRENCE Sch_Occ on 
       Sch_Occ.BASE_NAME=Exception.BASE_NAME)
     Left outer Join dbo.SATT_ROLES Roles ON 
       (Roles.ROLE_PK=Sch_Occ.ROLE_FK and 
       Roles.ROLE_NAME='Test-Role-POD1'))
    WHERE 
      (Exception.ITEM_DATE > GETDATE() - 90) AND 
      (Exception.asset_status <> 'IN SERVICE') 
      AND Exception.BASE_NAME='Test-Base' 
      --AND (Proc_Role.ROLE_NAME='Test-Role-POD1' or Roles.ROLE_NAME='Test-Role-POD1')
    GROUP BY 
      Exception.asset_name, Exception.asset_description,
      ITEM_DATE 
    HAVING 
      (Exception.asset_name IS NOT NULL) AND 
      (asset_name <> '') 
      AND (COUNT(Exception.asset_status) > 2) 
    ORDER BY 
      CountOfasset_status1 DESC
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What RDBMS?  How is query not doing what you want?  What is your desired output?  Please label your tables as you use them in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but you probably want:

```
(COUNT(distinct e.asset_status) > 2)
```

and this will cause you problems:

```
GROUP BY 
    e.asset_name, 
    e.asset_description,
    ITEM_DATE 

SELECT 
    DISTINCT(COUNT(e.asset_status)) AS CountOfasset_status1, 
    e.asset_name, 
    e.asset_description
```

you need to include item_date in your `select` clause or remove it from your `group by` clause

sry, I aliased your tables:

```
FROM 
    (((dbo.SATV_REP_EXCEPTION e 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SATV_PROCEDURE_ROLE p ON 
        (e.profile_name = p.TITLE AND 
        p.ROLE_NAME='Test-Role-POD1'))
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SATV_COR_SCHEDULE_OCCURRENCE o ON 
        o.BASE_NAME=e.BASE_NAME)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SATT_ROLES r ON 
        (r.ROLE_PK=Sch_Occ.ROLE_FK AND 
        r.ROLE_NAME='Test-Role-POD1'))
```

also, this stuff:

```
HAVING 
    (e.asset_name IS NOT NULL) AND 
    (asset_name <> '')  AND
```

can go in your `where` clause since there's no aggregate function performed